# Gradle: War Task has Conflicting Includes/Excludes

Tags: java, groovy, build, build-process, gradle

I am trying to build a war file with Gradle, but I'm having an issue excluding one directory and including another that happen to have the same names, but different parent directories.

Please notice in the first code example below that neither of the `css/` directories are being included in the final `war` file -- I assume because Gradle thinks that I want to exclude **any directory** named `css/` regardless of its absolute path.

Basically I want to exclude `src/main/webapp/css` and include `build/tmp/css` because the latter contains the minified code. How can I achieve this? I've tried specifying an absolute path in various ways but haven't had any success.

```
war {
  dependsOn minify
  from('build/tmp/') { include ('css/') }
  exclude('WEB-INF/classes/', 'css/')
}
```

If I don't exclude `css/` like so:

```
war {
  dependsOn minify
  from('build/tmp/') { include ('css/') }
  exclude('WEB-INF/classes/')
}
```

then the result is that both the minified and non-minified code is included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure why you exclude `WEB-INF/classes/css` instead of `src/main/webapp/css` in your build.gradle, but copying the minified CSS files instead of the original ones is achieved by:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
  // dependsOn 'minify'

  from 'src/main/webapp'
  exclude 'css' // or: "exclude 'WEB-INF/classes/css'"

  from('build/tmp/css') {
    include '**/*.css'
    into 'css' // or: "into 'WEB-INF/classes/css'"
  }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of `exclude('WEB-INF/classes/', 'css/')` is to exclude both of those directories actually. `css/` is not inside of `classes`. Other than that the `into 'css'` does seem to do the trick.