# gradle - how to exclude WEB-INF/classes from war

Tags: java, plugins, gradle, war

I have a fairly simple requirement. I have the following project layout:

```
project/build.gradle
 --src/main/java
 --src/main/res
```

What I would like to do is create a jar for all the java files in `project/src/main/java`

Include this **jar** file in the **war** and then exclude the `WEB-INF/classes` from the **war** file

### My `build.gradle` look as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'war'

dependencies {
..
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.0'
..
}

jar {
    archiveName = 'hello.jar'
}

war {
    dependsOn jar
    archiveName = 'hello.war'
    classpath fileTree(dir:'build/libs/',include:'*.jar')
    classpath configurations.compile
    webInf {
        from ('src/main/res') {
            include '**/*.*'
            into 'resources/'
        }
    }
}
```

---

I have tried various things to exclude `WEB-INF/classes` including the following snippets:

Using **rootSpec.exclude**:

```
war {
    dependsOn jar
    archiveName = 'hello.war'
    classpath fileTree(dir:'build/libs/',include:'*.jar')
    classpath configurations.compile
    rootSpec.exclude ('WEB-INF/classes')
    ...
}
```

Using **classpath**:

```
war {
    dependsOn jar
    archiveName = 'hello.war'
    classpath fileTree(dir:'build/libs/',include:'*.jar')
    classpath configurations.compile
    classpath fileTree(dir:'build/classes/', exclude:'*.class')
    ...
}
```

Using from `('war')`:

```
war {
    dependsOn jar
    archiveName = 'hello.war'
    classpath fileTree(dir:'build/libs/',include:'*.jar')
    classpath configurations.compile
    from ('war') {
       exclude('WEB-INF/classes')
    }
}
```

Doing a direct 'exclude':

```
war {
    dependsOn jar
    archiveName = 'hello.war'
    classpath fileTree(dir:'build/libs/',include:'*.jar')
    classpath configurations.compile
    exclude('WEB-INF/classes')
    ...
}
```

Which were all the suggestions I found online - but none of them seems to work. Any ideas what I am doing wrong.

Here are links to some of the articles and code I found:
[Gradle: War Task has Conflicting Includes/Excludes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752580/gradle-war-task-has-conflicting-includes-excludes)

[How to Exclude directory and its contents in gradle war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584402/how-to-exclude-directory-and-its-contents-in-gradle-war)

https://github.com/veny/smevente/blob/master/build.gradle

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-exlude-files-from-war-when-using-war-plugin-against-default-or-webappdirname-location/7366/6

The **gradle** version is ***2.12***.

Comment: Also very interested in this ... tried the same and nothing worked with Gradle 3.1-rc1

Answer (score 7):

Below is what worked for me, but you will still see an (harmless) empty package in the war bundle:

```
war {
    rootSpec.exclude('**/com/xxxxx/web/client/')
}
```

Comment: Had the same issue, and this worked for me too... What's the difference between putting `exclude 'blabla'` and `rootSpec.exclude('blabla')`?

Answer (score 1):

I looked to the articles and this code works:

```
  from 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes'
  exclude '**/*.class'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the massive trial and error. This worked for me:

war {

```
...

/* We bundle as a jar so that we can sign the jar.
 * So, we exclude our separate class files.
 */
rootSpec.exclude('**/com/**')

// include our jar file
classpath fileTree(dir:"${project.buildDir}/libs/",include:project.YourJarFileNm)

...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
from("./"){
        includes = [
            "a.log",
             "b.properties","src/**"             
        ]

        into 'WEB-INF/'
          }
       excludes = [
            "WEB-INF/misc/**"             
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to exclude the classes folder from WEB-INF

```
war{
  classpath = fileTree('*').exclude('**/classes')
}
```

I got this from http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Exclude-properties-file-from-war-td3365147.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
war {
    enabled = true
    classpath = classpath - sourceSets.main.output
    from (jar) {
        into 'WEB-INF/classes'
    }
}
```

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/war-task-should-allow-bundling-classes-into-jar/491

Answer (score -3):

This works for me:

```
war {
        dependsOn jar
        archiveName = 'hello.war'
        classpath = jar
    }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: it does not answer the question "how to exclude certain files from WAR"